# Javascript fails to create/recognize cookies on Chrome

Tags: javascript, cookies

I previously asked a question about why my Javascript didn't work, and was now gonna ask another one- when I finally decided to test my code on something else than my default browser, Google Chrome. And surprisingly, creating and reading cookies works on Internet Explorer 9 and jsfiddle.net, but not on Chrome! Anybody know why? Here's the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wpTLk/

Comment: Worked on Chrome 12.0.742.100

Comment: works on all major browsers i could get my hands on

Comment: Are you sure? Seems like other people have had this problem too            http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=23fd2349855c0f17&hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For those trying to use cookies for
>   local files, try adding the following
>   command line flag or switch to your
>   Chrome shortcut:

```
 --enable-file-cookies
```

> It should allow Chrome to accept local
>   file cookies.

Found this on http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=23fd2349855c0f17&hl=en