# Cookies. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

What this is suppose to do is a user enters their name (Using a text box) it will display their name on screen once they refresh the page, but for some reason it never gets into the if statement in getCookie. (It gets into the function get cookie though.)

---

```
function setCookie() {
    alert(fName.value);
    var user = fName.value;
    alert(user);
    var expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setTime(expiry.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60));
    document.cookie = "mydata=" + user + ";" + "expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
    alert();
}
```

---

```
function getCookie() {
alert(document.cookie.indexOf("mydata") >= 0);
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("mydata") >= 0) {
        alert();
        var cookieString = unescape(document.cookie);
        var list = cookieString.split("=");

        if(list[0] === "myData") {
            var data = list[1].split(",");
            var fname = list[0];
        }

    divisionbar.innerHTML = "Welcome Back" + data;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call those functions? Probably, there's your problem.

Comment: right off the bat, what is fName and are you passing it into your function?

Comment: setCookie is called when you move off the first name text box (<input type="text" name="fName" id = "fName" onblur = "setCookie()"> ) and then getCookie is called every time the website is loaded. (Inside init: getCookie();)

Edit: Also yes fname is being passed by using getElementById in init (fName = document.getElementById("fName");)

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this code locally? If so, I believe your problem is that your browser (most likely Chrome) is not allowing the creation of local cookies. See: [Javascript fails to create/recognize cookies on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449063/javascript-fails-to-create-recognize-cookies-on-chrome)

I tried your code in a slightly modified fashion on JSFiddle and it works as intended: http://jsfiddle.net/dKjas/

```
function setCookie(user) {
    alert(user);
    var expiry = new Date();
    expiry.setTime(expiry.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60));
    document.cookie = "mydata=" + user + ";" + "expires=" + expiry.toUTCString();
    alert(document.cookie);
}

function getCookie() {

    if (document.cookie.indexOf("mydata") >= 0) {
        var cookieString = unescape(document.cookie);
        var cookies = cookieString.split(";");

        for (var i = 0, len = cookies.length; i < len; i++){
            var data = cookies[i].split('=');
            if (data[0] === 'mydata') {
                // Change divisionbar here.
                alert('Name: ' + data[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

setCookie('foo');
getCookie();
```

I would sincerely recommend you move away from using global variables for accessing values and bits of the DOM, and also give those functions some more descriptive names :-)