# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

i have found this error like :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

in chrome how ever all other browser like Mozilla and IE doesn't give me this error.

and this is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){                 
     $(".thumb").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");return false;
     });
});
</script>
```

**----------------------------Updated---------------------------------------------**

i have also another script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            // Variables
            var objMain = $('#main');

            // Show sidebar
            function showSidebar() {
                objMain.addClass('use-sidebar');
                $.cookie('sidebar-pref2', 'use-sidebar', { expires: 30 });
            }

            // Hide sidebar
            function hideSidebar() {
                objMain.removeClass('use-sidebar');
                $.cookie('sidebar-pref2', null, { expires: 30 });
            }

            // Sidebar separator
            var objSeparator = $('#separator');

            objSeparator.click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (objMain.hasClass('use-sidebar')) {
                    hideSidebar();
                }
                else {
                    showSidebar();
                }
            }).css('height', objSeparator.parent().outerHeight() + 'px');

            // Load preference
            if ($.cookie('sidebar-pref2') == null) {
                objMain.removeClass('use-sidebar');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This works fine > http://jsfiddle.net/MvvTU/ The problem must be with another snippet of your code.

Comment: As @BenM said, it is correct. Try to make a pastebin or fiddle of your code, maybe we can help in better way.

Comment: @BenM - but chrome only show this portion has defect.

Comment: This error generally means that you've got an unclosed bracket somewhere, which makes JavaScript expect that closing bracket, instead of a `}`.

Comment: This code doesnt throw any error. The error is elsewhere. Chrome might show error in this part but you might added have opened/closed curly brackets at a wrong place elsewhere due to which chrome is unable to parse this part of code.

Comment: @BenM - when page load time this error occurred every time and how ever after i click something like link button of that master page then it's normal.

Comment: @BenM - ya i put other script in updated section that in master page portion. check it.

Comment: @shal nothing wrong with the updated code

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.location.href` instead of `window.location` as `window.location` is an `object` like,

```
window.location.href=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
```

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){                 
   $(".thumb").click(function(){
      window.location.href=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
      return false;
   });
});
```

Read [window.location Does Not Work on Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345807/window-location-does-not-work-on-chrome-browser)

**Updated,** Chrome doesn't support cookies for locals unless you start it with the `--enable-file-cookies flag`.

Read [Javascript fails to create/recognize cookies on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449063/javascript-fails-to-create-recognize-cookies-on-chrome)

Comment: This is an outdated issue - assigning a string to `window.location` is just an alias of `window.location.href` and works perfectly fine in chrome.

Comment: @shal try my updated answer.

Comment: @Emissary, it may be outdated for Chrome, but as of today, Brave throws the same error.

Comment: @Sablefoste I just downloaded the latest stable version and it seems fine - in any case the expected behaviour is written into the [JS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-location-interface), if there's a bug in a browser it should be reported as such.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){                 
         $(".thumb").click(function(){
         window.location.href=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
         });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: there is a difference. window.location is a Location object. window.location.href is a string representation of the location.

Comment: Yes, but assigning a string to `window.location` should work (it acts as an alias to the `.href`). Anyway, my point is that I don't think that it could explain the error about the `}`.